# Trouble with conflicting definitions regarding symmetric Laplacian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

On page 399 of Zaki & Meira$^\color{red}{\star}$, equation 16.7, I'm having a hard time understanding the symmetric graph Laplacian matrix given by

$$L^{sym}=\Delta^{-1/2}L\Delta^{-1/2}$$

Since $\Delta^{-1/2}$ is a diagonal matrix, then so will be $L^{sym}$. But this similar definition conflicts with that.

$$ L^{sym}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\delta_1}\sum\limits_{j = 1, j\ne 1}^n A_{1j} & -\frac{A_{12}}{\sqrt{\delta_1\delta_2}} & \ldots & -\frac{A_{1n}}{\sqrt{\delta_1\delta_n}} \\ -\frac{A_{21}}{\sqrt{\delta_2\delta_1}} & \frac{1}{\delta_2}\sum\limits_{j = 1, j\ne 2}^nA_{2j} & \ldots & -\frac{A_{2n}}{\sqrt{\delta_2\delta_n}} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ -\frac{A_{n1}}{\sqrt{\delta_n\delta_1}} & -\frac{A_{n2}}{\sqrt{\delta_n\delta_2}} & \ldots & \frac{1}{\delta_n}\sum\limits_{j = 1, j\ne n}^nA_{nj} \end{bmatrix} $$

Python (using numpy as np) even has disagreements with this.

```
A = np.array([
    [1,2,3], 
    [2,4,5],
    [3,5,6]]
)

# This Delta matrix is [6, 11, 14] in diagonal form
Delta = np.diag([sum(row) for row in A])

L = Delta - A

L_sym = (Delta ** -0.5) * L * (Delta ** -0.5)
```

Which will set `L_sym` to a diagonal matrix.

I'm pretty confused with this so any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

<sub>$\color{red}{\star}$ Mohammed J. Zaki, Wagner Meira, Jr, [Data Mining and Machine Learning — Fundamental concepts and algorithms](https://dataminingbook.info) (2nd edition) [[10 MB PDF](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/%7Ezaki/PaperDir/DMABOOK.pdf)], Cambridge University Press, March 2020. ISBN: 978-1108473989.</sub>

Comment: $L^{sym}$ isn't meant to be diagonal?

Comment: Consider any matrix $A$, and look at $I^{-1} A I$, where $I$ is the identity. The resulting matrix is *not* diagonal, even though $I$ *is*. Why does the fact that $\Delta$ is diagonal make you think that $L^{sym}$ must be? $L$ itself could be any matrix at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two definitions that you give for the symmetric Laplacian $L^{sym}$ are equivalent. To show this, we'll use two facts. First, let's see what happens to a matrix $A$ when we multiply it by a diagonal matrix $D$. If we multiply $A$ by $D$ on the left (i.e. $DA$), then we are scaling the rows of $A$ by the corresponding the diagonal entry. Similarly, if we multiply $A$ by $D$ on the right $DA$, we are scaling the columns of $A$ by the corresponding diagonal entry. The second fact is that if $D$ is a diagonal matrix, then $D^{-1/2}$ is simply taking inverse square roots of the diagonal entries (this is not true for a general matrix $A$). Using the definition of the original Laplacian $L$ and these two facts, the equivalence between your two definitions should be clear.

I think there are two places you might have had confusion. The first is what happens when you multiply a matrix by a diagonal matrix -- the result is not necessarily a diagonal matrix, just a row or column scaling of our original matrix, as mentioned above. Second, your Python code is incorrect. You currently have

```
L_sym = (Delta ** -0.5) * L * (Delta ** -0.5)
```

when you should be writing

```
L_sym = np.dot(np.dot(Delta ** -0.5, L), Delta ** -0.5)
```

The reason is that * corresponds to element-wise multiplication while np.dot corresponds to matrix and vector multiplications. In the future, be careful with the way you are taking $D^{-1/2}$ because I think ** is element-wise. As mentioned beforehand, this is the same thing for diagonal matrices but not for a general matrix. Lastly, your adjacency matrix should have zeros on the diagonal if your graph is simple (i.e. has no self edges).